# IOS. Cannot load file from Parse: issue "Too Many Open Files" using getDataInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, swift, file, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve image data stored in Parse, however when I do so, I get an error saying "too many open files" and it doesnt work.
It worked at first, with one image, but when I added a second one, it crashed. And now doesnt work anymore at all.

```
  if otherUser["profilePicture"] != nil {
      self.picProf = otherUser["profilePicture"] as! PFFile
      self.picProf.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                 if imageData != nil {
                     oneMember.profilePicFile = imageData!
                  } 
            }
            else {
                print(error)
            }
      })
  }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> BOMStorageOpenWithSys(const char *, Boolean, BomSys *): can't open: '/Users/viktor/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/X/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/Y/MyAPP11.app/Assets.car' Too many open files
>   2015-08-31 15:12:48.856 MyAPP11[1669:68206] Error: CUICommonAssetStorage -initWithPath: No storage file found at '/Users/viktor/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/X/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/Y/MyAPP11.app/Assets.car' errno: 'No such process'

**Do you have any idea how to resolve this excess of opened files ?**
I do not...

Thank you infinitely,

Comment: Try to check what the open files are first. Run this in your terminal and then launch your app : `sudo dtruss -n MyAPP11 2>&1 | grep open`

Comment: @deadbeef: Thank you for your input. I checked, and Im afraid I dont know how to run this in the terminal.      Regarding the issue, I have successful queries prior to the code exposed in my question. Do you think this could be the reason ?

Comment: Actually I don't know this seems very strange. The problem could also come from another process on you computer opening too many files (in which case rebooting should help).

Comment: For the Terminal command open Applications/Utilities/Terminal enter the command and give your password when asked.

Comment: @deadBeef: Thanks a lot. I will investigate all this further and get back to you.

Comment: @deadBeef: I think I might get why: The code is included in some loop, and the retrieving of the data might be called several times, causing a consecutive opening of the same file each time. Will attempt to resolve this, and update then if hypothesis is correct. Thanks

Comment: The loop repeating the code was indeed the issue. The "getDataInBackground" was called several times causing the surcharge of simultaneous files opened each times.   Thanks again. Question answered.